# the client running on android closes and exit application without exception or any message in function “connect (socket)” if the server is unreachable

Tags: android, sockets

I want to connect client TCP from android8/9/10 phone to PC windows 10 server application.
If the server is running all works fine, but  the client running on android closes and exits application without exception or any message in function “connect (socket)” if the server is unreachable. 
This happens in C++ ( android NDK) and Java. I am using Android studio 3.5.3.
The parts of code in C++ and java are:

```
    …
    try {
       int ressc = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
       if(ressc==0){
            …
       }
    }
    catch(...){
       std::exception_ptr p = std::current_exception();
    }
    ….

    /////Java

    …..
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
    } catch (SocketException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    …
```

I am trying to catch the case when the server is not reachable. 
Please help me in solving the problem.

```
Logcat is:
020-02-06 16:02:11.909 18810-18810/com.gstoilov.opencv_ndk V/OpenCV-NDK-Java: surfaceChanged format=4, width=1080, height=1080
2020-02-06 16:02:25.827 18810-18810/com.gstoilov.opencv_ndk I/Choreographer: Skipped 1052 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-02-06 16:02:25.907 18810-18915/com.gstoilov.opencv_ndk I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=17620ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=817735142460428, Vsync=817752675793060, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=817752683403284, AnimationStart=817752683557816, PerformTraversalsStart=817752685522712, DrawStart=817752699312503, SyncQueued=817752735797243, SyncStart=817752735903232, IssueDrawCommandsStart=817752736699222, SwapBuffers=817752761843180, FrameCompleted=817752763080993, DequeueBufferDuration=5291000, QueueBufferDuration=202000, 
2020-02-06 16:02:25.926 18810-18810/com.gstoilov.opencv_ndk D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-02-06 16:02:25.931 18810-18810/com.gstoilov.opencv_ndk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gstoilov.opencv_ndk, PID: 18810
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1042)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1009)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:959)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:920)
        at com.gstoilov.opencv_ndk.MainActivity.JavaBitmapFromNativeMat(MainActivity.java:615)
        at com.gstoilov.opencv_ndk.MainActivity$3$1.run(MainActivity.java:366)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6706)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2020-02-06 16:02:25.942 18810-18810/com.gstoilov.opencv_ndk I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18810 SIG: 9
```

Comment: So is it the C++ code or the Java code that causes the application to exit?

Comment: Both of them have the same effect

Comment: Does Logcat display anything relevant?

Comment: Is that what logcat says? I don't think that's what logcat says. I think that's what the debugger says.

Comment: I/Choreographer: Skipped 1052 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread...….
 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM.....

Comment: Is that all? There's probably something relevant before "Shutting down VM....". And since it will be long, put it in the question by clicking "edit".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the idea and the lesson.
After I checked the logcat I understood that the main thread tried to show a bitmap, but the socket was blocking for 30 seconds (default timeout) the current thread and couldn’t create this bitmap. The main thread was closing the VM and there were not emitted exception in the current thread.